# MySQL select Display Zero when group by month or week

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a column date and a column ID (to keep it simple). I am doing a query to count the total and group by week

```
SELECT MONTH(table1.Date_1st), YEAR(table1.Date_1st),  COUNT(table1.Id)
FROM table1 as table1
WHERE Date_1st BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2013-07-25'
GROUP BY WEEK(Date_1st)
```

the problem is there is no results on specific week the result is not taken into consideration. I already try `ifnull(table1.Id,0)`

Comment: what is expected result ?

Comment: Thanks Prix, I look into that option but is there a better way specially if I want to group by week?

Answer (score -1):

Try `ISNULL` or other `NULL` SQL functions:

[NULL functions](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp)

ISNULL returns a 0 if the value is null.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the prompt reply, in mysql will be ifnull right?, I already try that option before, and didnt worked, thank you very much for the link and thank you very much if you have other ideas and you can let me know!